# Mysqli get array from database and format to string

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm trying to get array of fields from database:

```
$query=("SELECT firstname FROM users");
$res = $connect->query($query);
```

Target is to display first name of every users:

`echo $firstname`

*Output:*

`Firstname1,Firstname2,Firstname3`

I know should be easy, if I just knew more.

Comment: http://us3.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php

Comment: can you more clear please whats you wants..

Comment: http://www.mysqltutorial.org/php-querying-data-from-mysql-table/

Comment: @user1741397..Please make it clear..

Comment: I tried  code in mysqli_fetch_array documentation, its returning only 1 username (row[0] row[1]). its not exactly what i am looking for.

Comment: `while ($rows = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){ $firstname = $rows['firstname'] . ", "; echo $firstname; }` <= there.

Comment: I have a table of users with first name and last names, i want to take all users Firstname and output it like this: Firstname1,fisrtname2,firstnam3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For getting all records or a set of records you have to fetch each records inside a `while` loop.

```
$query=mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT firstname FROM users");  // execute the query
$string="";
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query))    // fetch each records
{
   $string.=$row['firstname']).',';      // append the firstname to a variable
}
echo $string;                          // output the constructed variable with all firstnames
```

Comment: Thank you, i am going to use all firstname results outside of the while in other part of my code , so need to prepare a string and store it in a variable?

Comment: Thank you very very much! exactly what i was looking for. too bad i couldn't explain better and figure it out earlier.. 4 hours spent on it! :(

Comment: @user1741397..Glad to help you :)